# Regular expressions - check for a word within a string that startswith "Something"

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following USER_AGENT header as a string

"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4"

What I'd like to is search this string for any word that startswith, say, "Version" - but I'd like to also grab the whole "word" it is a part of - so, for this example we have "Version/10.1.1". My current regex lookup is just returning back "Version"...so any pro-regex tips would be great.

Here is my attempted code:

```
import re

http_user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4"

if 'Safari' in http_user_agent and 'Mobile' not in http_user_agent:
    version = re.compile(r'\b({0}).*?'.format('Version'), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search(http_user_agent)
    print(version.group(0))
```

The print of version.group(0) is currently just "Version"....help!

This regex works but it feels a little lazy:

```
(Version.*? )
```

Answer (score 3):

The lazy `.*?` at the end of the pattern always matches an empty string, you may safely remove it from the pattern and instead add the`\S*` pattern that matches 0 or more characters other than whitespace chars:

```
version = re.compile(r'\b{0}\S*'.format('Version'), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search(http_user_agent)
                              ^^^
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FaMZlv) yielding `Version/10.1.1` as output.

Note you do not need a capturing group around `Version`, so I'd also suggest removing the capturing parentheses from the pattern.

Note that you may precise the pattern to only match `Version` followed with `/` and dot-sepatated numbers using

```
re.compile(r'\b{0}/\d+(?:\.\d+)*'.format('Version'), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/jhWsYs) and a [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Php3Q0/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `Version` - a literal substring
- `/` - a `/` char
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)*` - a non-capturing group matching 0 or more (due to `*` at the end) repetitions of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:-

```
import re

http_user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4"

if 'Safari' in http_user_agent and 'Mobile' not in http_user_agent:
    version = re.compile(r'\b({0}).*?'.format('Version[/\.\d]*\s'), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search(http_user_agent)
    print(version.group(0))
```

Here we have changed regex `Version` to `Version[/\.\d]*\s` to include number '.' and '/' till the space character.